# Delegate is not being set

Tags: delegates, swift

I have a class Document (subclass of NSDocument) with a property (called documentString) which, when changed, should call it's delegate. In my case, the delegate is a ViewController. Though the delegate is being set in the ViewController, it appears to be nil and the function with which the ViewController should respond is not being called

This is the property whose change should be reported to the delegate(always prints "no").

```
var documentString: String {
    didSet {
        if self.delegate != nil {
            self.delegate?.documentContentDidChange()
        } else {
            println("no")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the ViewController.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, DocumentDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var codeView: NSTextView!
    var code: Document = Document()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.code.delegate = self
        self.updateUI()                            
    }

    func documentContentDidChange() {
        self.updateUI()
    }

    func updateUI() {
        self.codeView.string = self.code.documentString
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I added `println("no1")` after `self.code.delegate = self`. no gets printed before no1. So it means that delegate is not being set when documentString is changed. But then, updateUI should work properly with codeView displaying the text in documentString. However, codeView remains blank.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint or println in viewDidLoad to ensure the function is called?

Comment: didSet is getting called before the ViewController has a chance to set itself as the delegate.  Do you know what is doing that?  (Also, why are you using an optional in didSet after you have already confirmed a non-nil value?)